# Web method that returning list getting as array

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

My web methods are returning some values as list, but while calling these web methods getting it as array objects.How can I get it same as list.My web method is similar like this

```
        [WebMethod]
        public List<ReturnList> GetReturnList()
        {
           List<ReturnList> ReturnList=new List<ReturnList>();
        //Calcuations
            return ReturnList;
        }
```

Comment: I haven't used "web service", but there may be a configuration that you need to set the on client side to get it as a list not array.

Comment: I couldn't find out such a configuration,Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: List<T> is a .Net structure. Think, when someone wants to consume your service in Java or on some other platform.

Comment: right click your service reference , there was an option to configure this thing. I do not know where it was exactly but it was somewhere on the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your web method definition is not lacking anything.  Lists will be converted to arrays because of SOAP and how it is defined and structured.  If you really need a list when consuming the method, convert the array back into a List where you're consuming it.  You could also make a web service wrapper where you could wrap that web method and return a List<> instead of an array. The method body would just call the web service and convert the array to List<> and return it.

Check [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-PH/asmxandxml/thread/e45222f3-d0a5-465b-8718-39fc3f9406e2)

Answer (score 3):

The List is more of a language specific data structure. All the language specific data types will be mapped to language neutral data types which is XML data types.

When request/response is happening the XML mapping will occur, thus by platform and language interoperability has achieved.

```
The reason that the List kind of data types are not getting as the same data type,
  because there is no equivalent XML data type available.
```

So, you can have a utility to convert the List to array or vice versa to fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```html
  [WebMethod]
    public static Details[] GetData()
    {
        DataSet dsDetails = new DataSet();
        List<Details> details = new List<Details>();
        try
        {
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("String");
            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetDetails");
            
            dsDetails = (DataSet)db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
            foreach (DataRow dtrow in dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Details report = new Details();
                report.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["ID"].ToString());
                report.ReferenceID = Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["ReferenceID"].ToString());
                report.ProductID = dtrow["Name"].ToString();
                
                details.Add(report);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {

        }

        return details.ToArray();
    }
```